# Select all products that have a custom field 'is_new' set to 'Yes'

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How can I select all products that have a custom field 'is_new' set to 'Yes'?

This is what I tried:

```
$loop = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'tax_query'         => [
        'taxonomy'      => 'is_new',
        'terms'         => 'YES',
        'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
    ]
]);
```

Unfortunately, this just gives me all products.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to do a "taxonomy query". This is for things like tags and categories. Custom fields are stored as *meta*, so you need to do a meta query.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => [
        [
            'key'   => 'is_new',
            'value' => 'Yes',
        ],
    ],
] );
```

There's a few other differences to take note of:

- From your screenshot, the value for yes is `Yes`, not `YES`.
- Taxonomy and meta queries need to be an array of arrays. See how my meta query is an array inside another array.
- Since it's not a taxonomy query, we use `compare` instead of `operator`, but the default value for that is `=`, which we want, so we can omit it.